# Configuring Apache, PHP & MySQL Mac

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache

I've been trying for a week now to configure Apache, PHP and MySQL. I feel like I messed all my root directories. I'm new at this so I take commands and enter it in the terminal blindly. 
I tried to configure it with out macports at first then failed, then I tried Macports, and also failed to view a simple PHP file on my browser.
What to do? Please help

OS: Mac OS Sierra v10.12

Comment: Start over, use MAMP.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to give more details on what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use MAMP is simple and based on XAMPP. Then you can add the php files to your `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` folder and access with `localhost:PortNumber/file.php`

Answer (score 0):

Even this happened for me too. i reseted my machine into factory reset mode then i tried and it works now.